# how to remove glow effect in flutter listview widget?

Tags: performance

**How to make listview not glow?**

IS there a way for it?

When you try to scroll views there is a glow effect appears. It's blue on ICS and above. I need to make it green. I've read a lot of topics and noticed that there is no easy solution to change this glow effect color so I've decided to completly remove this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glow effect comes from GlowingOverscrollIndicator added by ScrollBehavior.

To remove this effect, you need to specify a custom ScrollBehavior. For that, simply wrap any given part of your application into a ScrollConfiguration with the desired ScrollBehavior.

The following ScrollBehavior will remove the glow effect entirely:

```
class NoGlow extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Use this for behavior parameter in the list view.

```
    ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: NoGlow(),
  child: ListView(
    ...
  ),
)
```

This will remove that glow effects.

Comment: sorry I asked an already existed question. Thank you for answering it